# how to add an phtml file in xml file of magento?

Tags: magento

i am a new learner of magento, now, to learn, i want to add some content in the category list page,

1,i add a file named add.phtml, in which i typed `<h1>example test</h1>`.(base\default\template\catalog\product\add.phtml)

2,in `\base\default\layout\catalog.xml` i added the following

```
  <action method="addPagerLimit" translate="label"><mode>list</mode><limit>all</limit><label>All</label></action>
                        -->
                    </block>
                    <block type="catalog/product_blog" name="add" template="catalog/product/add.phtml"/>
```

under

```
<!--
Category default layout
-->
```

part.

why on the category page, there is no show example test.thank you

Comment: Does class `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Blog` exist in your project?

Answer (score 0):

The `type` attribute indicates which Block (php class) it should use. In you case it will search in catalog/block/product/blog.php. Unless you added a Blog.php the right way, it will break on that part as this is not default magento.

Answer (score 0):

Hello i think you can create custom module & override layout xml in your custom layout xml
this tips may be help you

Answer (score 0):

Use bellow code to add your phtml file in category list page.

copt this paste it in to catelog/layer/left.phpml file Or any file where you want.

getLayout()->createBlock('core/template')->setTemplate('catalog/product/add.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>